# Using @import in objective C in conjunction with __cplusplus

Tags: ios, objective-c++, directive

When I try to compile an Objective C++ file (.mm) that is linked to a file that uses the new @import directive, I get some errors. Currently, my only solution is to replace the @import with the old #import directive.

Is there any other solution so I can still use @import?

Comment: Which errors specifically?

Comment: Build failed "Unexpected '@' in program"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit**:
According to the latest docs this should work now.

See [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#command-line-parameters). You have to use the `-fcxx-modules` flag instead of the `-fmodules` flag, but as the official documentation suggests - `EXPERIMENTAL and VERY BROKEN`. I didn't manage to get it working at all... In my opinion it's better to stick with `#import` and `#include` until that feature is out of `experimental` stage.

From [clang.llvm.org](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#command-line-parameters):

```
-fcxx-modules
    Enable the modules feature for C++ (EXPERIMENTAL and VERY BROKEN).
```

Comment: @kevlar that answer was from more than three years ago.. According to the docs it should work now. Haven't tried it myself yet, though.

Comment: Sorry for the dull question but where do you set this flag

Comment: @IvanGenchev The documentation is update. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: Can you please help me that where do you set this flag in xcode ?

Comment: I added it to `Build Settings` -> Other C++ Flags and compiled with me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to use OpenCV in my application.

I have solved this problem by adding

`-fcxx-modules` (Objective C++) manually to "Other C++ Flags"

*(Build Settings/ Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags/ Other C++ Flags)*

or

`-fmodules` (Objective C) to "Other C Flags"

*(Build Settings/ Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags/ Other C Flags)*

And also I needed to put import the `opencv.hpp` before any Apple's headers to fix errors of Expected identifier in opencv library.
For example in `Prefix.pch` I organized it that way:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#import <Availability.h>
```

I am using:

- Xcode - 11.3
- CocoaPods - 1.9.1
- OpenCV2 - 4.3.0