# "Use of '@import' when modules are disabled" Error - Enable Modules & Link Frameworks = YES

Tags: ios, xcode, module, cocoapods

I have a project that uses CocoaPods and uses the 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C' pod. That pod uses the `@import UIKit;` module style import. I've set "Enable Modules (C & Objective-C)" and the "Link Frameworks Automatically" to YES in both my target and project settings. I am still getting the "Use of '@import' when modules are disabled" error.

Is there anything that could prevent Xcode from being able to enable Modules such as the use of a .pch file, any linker flags, or anything else I haven't mentioned? I also tried to clean the project and the project build folder. That didn't have any effect.

Also worth noting is that my project has multiple targets and also has a deployment target of iOS 7.0. My Base SDK is set to iOS 8.3.

[image: Screenshot of target build settings for modules]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem with Google Analytics. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I guess your project contains XXX.mm files, however, the xcode only enable C and objective-c modules.

Please have a look at this answer for your reference:
[Using @import in objective C in conjunction with __cplusplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708262/using-import-in-objective-c-in-conjunction-with-cplusplus)

my solution is modify the @import xxx into #import .

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, only #import works.  Could not get modules working due to the same error described here.   #import <Firebase/Firebase.h> works

Answer (score 6):

I just solved this in a primarily ObjC++ project I was working on that needed to use Firebase.

Simply make a ObjC (`.m`) file which contains the following.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import Firebase; // << swap this for your specific import
```

That's it, then simply use `#include` in your `.mm` files for the specific headers you need. For me that meant:

```
#include <"Firebase/Firebase.h">
#include <"FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h">
```

Just to stress the point, no amount of fiddling with link options made any difference to this `"Enable Modules (C & Objective-C)"` was already `YES`. Upgrading to XCode7 didn't seem to help.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I've done this.  Same error in the newly added .m Objective-C file.   I have no .mm files.   Checked everything outlined in this thread.  Still same error.   Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 3):

The build option does not really work as it should. I've solved this problem by adding -fcxx-modules (Objective C++) or -fmodules (Objective C) manually to "C Flags"/"C++ Flags".

Worked for me.