# Invoking swift in objective-C++ (.mm file)

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c++

Can one invoke Swift code in a Objective-C++ (.mm) file? Are there any simple workarounds if not?

I have a Xcode project that is a mix of Swift, Objective-C and C++. I have no problem going from Objective-C to Swift with the `-Bridging-Header.h` or from Swift to Objective-C with the `-Swift.h`.

I do however have a .mm file which is Objective-C++. When I try to `#import "[ProductName]-Swift.h"` it throws many compile errors in the `-Swift.h` file such as:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSApplicationDelegate', did you
>   mean 'NSConnectionDelegate'?
>
> No type protocol named 'NSTableViewDataSource'

etc...

I have looked into several other similar questions such as [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24042774/4504933) but it does not seem to give me an explicit answer or a solution.

As I see it, my current workaround is to create a wrapper object in Objective-C that uses the Swift code and then import that into the Objective-C++ code.

Comment: Maybe the problem has to do with the fact that `@import` statements do not work with Objective-C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just succeeded in compiling a .mm file invoking swift by adding `-fcxx-modules` flag. The `<Module>-Swift.h` file generated by Xcode includes `@import` and checks for modules support. Found out the flag from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20708695/2570853.

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the flag?

Comment: Double click the file in build phases and enter the flag.